# How RPM and dnf databases are maintained?

Tags: package-management, rpm, dnf

Does dnf and rpm uses the same database to store details about installed packages.? Can someone mention the path of database created by rpm and dnf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RPM database is contained in `/var/lib/rpm`. DNF is a package manager that installs, updates, and removes packages on RPM-based Linux distributions. It is the successor to YUM (Yellowdog Updater, Modified) and is known as "Dandified Yum". DNF purports to have improved performance and better dependency resolution than its YUM predecessor.

Comment: Does dnf also use database in `/var/lib/rpm` or it will maintain its own?

Comment: Whether you use the `rpm` package manager, the `yum` package manager or the `dnf` package manager (which supersedes `yum`)  the same underlying database (`/var/lib/rpm`) is used.